# unable to get the correct http response mapped in angular 2 code

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway and I am making calls to my API using angular 2 code, the problem is when the session token expires and my UI Code tries to use it - API Gateway throws a 403 Error stating "The security token included in the request is expired" .. This is what I am able to see in my console - Network Section.

Now this 403 Error is caught in the Promise code => catch Handler and I try to show the message being sent by the server i.e

```
{"message":"The security token included in the request is expired"}
```

here's the problem - that I am unable to show the correct error message in console and in Sweet Alert Box.

On Debuging the error object received by the Catch Handler, this Json is shown - where the actual error object is not there.

```
{"data":"","status":0,"statusText":"","headers":{},"config":{"method":"GET","headers":{"x-api-key":"<api-key>","Accept":"application/json","x-amz-date":"201705957Z","Authorization":"AWS4-HM256 Credential=ASIAJ66A/20170317/us-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date;x-api-key, Signature=59a2bce53fc3fc25a0dcc36c80243ae63","x-amz-security-token":"<security-token>","Content-Type":"application/json"},"timeout":0,"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://api.tech.in/adviser/Suraj","data":""}}
```

I was able to solve this for a 400 error which was sent by API Gateway on giving wrong paswsord or username.

Note: CORS is enabled & Mapping Response and Integration has 403 Error Mapped with Error to be shown Headers have CORS.

What to do - to solve this issue - as the final Error Object caught in catch handler doesn't have the correct http response data

Here's my code

```
// this is the final Consumer of the Promise
this.http.getFundDetailedList() //***
        .then(response => this.fundDetailsList = response.data.Items)
        .catch(err => {
        swal('Error Reported', "Please login again \n"+err.data, 'error');
        console.log(this.handleError(err));
        });
    }

    // helper function for Error Handling
private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    console.log('Error Json '+ JSON.stringify(error)); // Wrong Error Object shown in console
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : JSON.stringify(error.data.message);
    }
    return errMsg;
  }


  // Calls AWS API - coded inside a http service class
  getFundDetailedList() {
    return this.credentialService.getAwsSDK().adviserFundsGet({ 'adviser': this.credentialService.$id }, {}, {});
  }
```

Comment: What is a security token?

Comment: Can you add the code of the http call?

Comment: security token is half removed - its used by AWS Securiy and all, ... uploading my code in a min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS headers are not sent correctly for Authentication failures in API Gateway. This is a known issue, you can find more details on the aws forums

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=671237&#720951

Essentially, with certain types of errors (authentication failure/bad request/api key auth/issues calling integration) the header mappings are skipped which means CORS headers are not returned in the response.

We apologize for the inconvenience. But we are actively working on fixing this.

Comment: Thanx for the clarification ... and its a request to update this post with estimated date of getting this bug fixed. It would be helpful to other viewers as well.